# Sync Promises for initialize MongoDB database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous

I'm new to web development but I have those questions regarding MongoDB and Nodejs driver, given this code:

```
let MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const url = MY_URL;
const dbConnected = MongoClient.connect(url);
let dbInit =  function (){
    dbConnected.then(
        (client) => {
            let db = client.db('DB_NAME');
            db.dropDatabase()
                .then( () => {})
                .catch( err => { throw err;})
            return client;
        }
    )
    .then(
        (client) =>{
            let db = client.db('knodels');
            db.collection('Users').insertMany([
                //data
            ])
            .then( () => {})
            .catch( err => { throw err;})
            return client;
       }
    )
    .then(
        (client) =>{            
            client.close();
        }
    )
    .catch((err) => {throw err;})
}
```

I want to achieve those things:

1. drop the database
2. create the database after the drop and populate it
3. close connection

All this goals are achieved when I run the function but I think there is something wrong with the code:

- when `dbInit()` is run some `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` are thrown
- there is definitely something funky with the sync of those promises that have to be async I guess
- catching of errors is done only at the end or for all promises?
- the promise for closing the client connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets name some of the code segments,

```
let dbInit =  function (){
dbConnected.then(
    (client) => {
        //////////////////////TASK 1/////////////////////
        let db = client.db('DB_NAME');
        db.dropDatabase()
            .then( () => {})
            .catch( err => { throw err;})
        return client;
       //////////////////////TASK 1/////////////////////
    }
)
.then(
    (client) =>{
        //////////////////////TASK 2/////////////////////
        let db = client.db('knodels');
        db.collection('Users').insertMany([
            //data
        ])
        .then( () => {})
        .catch( err => { throw err;})
        return client;
        //////////////////////TASK 2/////////////////////
   }
)
.then(
    (client) =>{            
        client.close();
    }
)
.catch((err) => {throw err;})
}
```

In a promise chain, Like the one above, A then block will execute once the predecessor then is resolved. 
Which means the then block containing `TASK 2` would only execute once `TASK 1` is complete.

But since you are **not** returning a promise from `TASK 1`, instead returning a truthy value (the variable client) and since truthy values are treated as promise resolution. It might/could start executing  `db.collection('Users').insertMany...` even before the drop is complete.

A similar thing would apply to the next then block where the client.close will be called before the insert is complete.

So instead of returning client everywhere, return the db operation, its a promise and that would make the chain sequential.

Also you don't need such a nested chain, with catches at every promise,
Something like

```
let connection = null;
dbConnected.then((client) => {
  connection = client;  
  const db = client.db('DB_NAME');
  return db.dropDatabase()
}).then(() => {
  // Perform insert and return a promise//
}).then(() => {
  return connection.close();
}).catch((err) => {
   // handle error //
})
```

should do the job!!

Comment: Thank you man, so much clear! Didn't even thought of carring around the connection with a "global" variable.